# Query for existence of an object with LINQ (to Entities)

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

(I've put "...to Entities" in brackets since I don't know if this matters at all. I guess this is a quite general LINQ related question.)

I want to check with LINQ (to Entities) if an object exists in the database. At the moment I am doing the following:

```
using (MyEntitiesContext aCtx = new MyEntitiesContext())
{
    var aQuery = from c
                 in aCtx.Client
                 where c.ClientID==1
                 select c;

    Client aClient = aQuery.FirstOrDefault();

    bool Exists = (aClient!=null);
    ...
}
```

But (if I am not wrong) this loads the full Client object from the database (if the Client exists). I am actually only interested whether it exists or not without loading the object.

SQL has the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` construct. Is there something similar I can do with LINQ?

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.any.aspx)  method of IQueryable. It will return a boolean value indicating whether or not an object was found matching the specified condition.

```
using (MyEntitiesContext aCtx = new MyEntitiesContext())
{
    bool exists = (from c
                   in aCtx.Client
                   where c.ClientID==1
                   select c).Any();
}
```

This method will also stop running as soon as it evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

I would then use `Any()` to determine existence. Regardless of whether you create a dummy instance like the following, the compiler will create a SQL statement using the Exists function and thus, it will not matter what is in the Select statement.

```
var query= from c
            in context.Client
            where c.ClientID == 1
            select new { Dummy = "foo" };

var exists = query.Any();
```

Comment: Hm, does this mean that without this dummy object the `Any()` method would still cause the Client object to be loaded from the database?

Comment: There is no "dummy instance" here, despite what the answer says. The code shown will never materialize/instantiate any instance. Try it and see; the code works correctly even if the text above it is a little misleading.

Comment: OK, I understand. But then does it make any difference to write `select new { Dummy = "foo" }` instead of `select c` as the other answers suggested?

Comment: @Slauma - Remember that LINQ does not actually execute until you use the query so the query gets executed on the call to `Any`. Thus, it is technically correct to say that the Dummy instance never gets created. By "create", I should have said "declare" which I'll change here shortly. If you use Select c, I believe the system will query for c using Select *. That I'll have to test.

Comment: @Slauma - Looking at the resulting SQL, it shouldn't matter whether you use `select c` or create a dummy instance. When you use `Any`, the compiler is smart enough to use an `Exists` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
using (MyEntitiesContext aCtx = new MyEntitiesContext())
{
     var aQuery = from c
         in aCtx.Client
         where c.ClientID==1
         select c;

     int total = aQuery.Count();

     bool Exists = (total > 0);
     ...
}
```

Untested...

Comment: [Never use `Count()` when you mean `Any()`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Count() operator or the Any Operator on your query to check if it would return a result:

```
using (MyEntitiesContext aCtx = new MyEntitiesContext())
{
    var aQuery = from c
                 in aCtx.Client
                 where c.ClientID==1
                 select c;

    int count = aQuery.Count();

    bool Exists = (count > 0);

    // or
    Exists = aQuery.Any();

    ...
}
```